# get_template_part in a foreach loop and access to a var of item

Tags: php, wordpress

i have an error with this code :

front-page.php :

```
<?php $categories = get_categories( array( 'taxonomy' => 'category', 'parent' => 0, 'hide_empty' => 0 ) ); ?>

<?php get_template_part( 'templates/categories-list' ); ?>
```

categories-list.php :

```
<?php global $categories; ?><?php /* for get $categories from front-page.php */ ?>

<?php foreach ( $categories as $cat ) : ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'templates/category-meta' ); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

category-meta.php :

```
<?php global $cat; ?><?php /* for get $cat from categories-list.php */ ?>

<?php var_dump($cat); ?>
```

$cat is empty, why ? how to do ?

Comment: Instead of a <?php var_dump($cat); ?> ,    do <?php var_dump($categories); ?> in category-meta.php to see  what it contains. I think that in categories-list.php your foreach overwrites the $cat variable.

Comment: so, <?php var_dump($categories); ?> in category-meta.php return : null

Comment: Then most probably get_categories function is not working.

Answer (score 4):

I solved my problem by using include && locate_template

```
<?php include( locate_template( 'templates/category-meta.php' ) ); ?>
```